# Need help in to extract values to new row in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I kinda need help extracting a value from a string and dynamically add new row

Below is the string that I have in the column **DBInfo**.

> [{"DBName":"master","TriggerName":"ramp_sqlpreventivetrigger_sqlserver_v01","TriggerStateDB":"Enabled"},{"DBName":"master","TriggerName":"No Trigger","TriggerStateDB":"No Trigger"}]

As you can see, we have two sets of data in above string. **master** database is coming twice so i need rows instead of one row.

Below is what I have so far.
I am using **substring** and **trim** for now to remove "**]**" and "**[**" from the string so that I can use **parse_json** function. I am not having any luck so far.

```
SQLTriggerViolations 
| where TriggerStatus != "Enabled"
| where ServerName == 'ServerName'
| project ServerName, DBInfo
| extend DBInfoModified = substring(DBInfo, 1, strlen(DBInfo))
| extend DBInfoFinal = trim("]", DBInfoModified)
| extend DBName = parse_json(DBInfoFinal).TriggerName
```

Comment: **(1)** Array is a valid JSON and by trimming the square brackets you actually get an invalid JSON for cases where you have more than one element within the array. **(2)** Even the trimming was not done right. This would have work: `substring(DBInfo, 1, strlen(DBInfo) - 2)`, or this: `trim(@"^\[|]$", DBInfo)` or this: `parse DBInfo with "[" DBInfoTrimmed "]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `mv-expand`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator

for example:

```
datatable(DBInfo:string)
[
    '[{"DBName":"master","TriggerName":"ramp_sqlpreventivetrigger_sqlserver_v01","TriggerStateDB":"Enabled"},{"DBName":"master","TriggerName":"No Trigger","TriggerStateDB":"No Trigger"}]'
]
| mv-expand parse_json(DBInfo)
```

| DBInfo |
| --- |
| { "DBName": "master", "TriggerName": "ramp_sqlpreventivetrigger_sqlserver_v01", "TriggerStateDB": "Enabled" } |
| { "DBName": "master", "TriggerName": "No Trigger", "TriggerStateDB": "No Trigger" } |

Comment: Wow. This was so easy. I didn't know mv-expand can be so powerful. Thanks a ton Yoni. You saved my day.